# how to login a windows server which is having private ip alone via centos minimal

Tags: windows, centos7, remote-access

I need a help from you, is there any tool/setting to ssh a windows server via centos minimal. if yes kindly suggest/advice me..

have tried this below article but it does't works https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49301

Many Thanks !!! Johnson

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an SSH server in windows by installing the following applications one of them is enough.

- [Kpym](http://www.kpym.com/2/kpym/index.htm) (telnet / ssh server)
- [MobaSSH](https://mobassh.mobatek.net/) (ssh server)

I recommend MobaSSH because it has a much bigger community and support. Install this one on the windows machine and you are good to go.

Comment: AmilaMGunawardana in my case i don't have a GUI in my OperatingSystem

Comment: @AntonyJohnson this one has to install in windows environment

Comment: Understood but how can i login into that windows server which is having internal IP alone :(

Comment: After you install the client open the port 22 on the windows using windows firewall inbound rules. And you internal IP can be used to access the windows machine by SSH.

Comment: fine thanks let me check and confirm

Comment: Any luck on connecting to the server?

Comment: AmilaMGunawardana no i can't able to connect :(

Comment: Do you have the windows server ip? Try telnet to the windows server port 22. In linux machine or other machine put telnet <windows ip> 22